# Is it possible for several local SWFs to share a local SharedObject the way clients can share a remote SharedObject on a server?

Tags: actionscript-3

Using ActionScript, When several clients are connected to a remote SharedObject it functions as a 'live' data exchange, where all clients are updated whenever any client makes a change.  It obviously works because only the server has actual access to the file, and simply broadcasts the change.

Is there a way to enable the same type of functionality between several local swf files loaded into stand-alone projectors?

Specifically:  A user can run several (some have 60 or more....) instances of an online game client, which includes a map of the identical virtual world.  Rather than have every instance load the same map into memory, it would save MUCH (The map is larger than Georgia..) memory if they could all access the same data.

A sharedObject would obviously create file access headaches since each client  needs read/write access.  Is there some other technology available or a way to load an auxiliary swf perhaps to function as the 'server'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do similar things with Flash [SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html). You've pretty much found the name, you just had to search for it :)

Check out the [getLocal](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#getLocal%28%29) method - it allows you to access a locally persisted information from multiple files.

Few things:

- Keep in mind to set a proper `localPath` in order to be able to read the data from multiple files.
- Keep in mind that this storage is first limited, and this limitation is commonly defined by the user.
- Another **crucial** thing is that the local storage can be denied by the user. Which means that it's not sure that you can always write there.
- While it can be used with a Flash Media Server, the standard local storage won't dispatch events when the property is changed. You need to create your own script if you need real time updates.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Nope.  Does not work.   Using the example from the API,  change the 'clear' function to reload mySo.  Run an instance, set a value.  Open another, it reads the correct value.  Now try to write again.  The first instance never gets the change.  Open another instance, it gets the correct value.   Add a button to close and re-read the SO.  Still no go.  (I even tried with a setTimeout) An open instance will never get updated, any new instance will always read the last saved value correctly...  Any running instance always sees only its own changes..

Comment: Did you set the same **custom** `localPath` for all those instances? If you did not provide such, it won't work. And if you read the manual, it's said that this is possible, so.. :)

Comment: actually, the API for the getLocal() method states: 'Returns a reference to a locally persistent shared object that is only available to the current client.' but! There is a partial solution: no matter how many clients share the object, the last one to write to it is always persistent, so closing the SO & reopening it will retrieve the current value.  Unfortunately, there are no events you can subscribe to since SharedObject does not extend EventDispatcher. this does give me more than enough functionality, I believe